# How to add an extra field to a media element in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

I would like to add an extra field to each media element, eg. next to the default title and description fields.

In `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_metadata.php` I've added the following code, but I am not seeing the new field in the backend:

```
$tempColumns = [
    'my_field' => [
        'label' => 'My Field',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'items' => [
                ['Default', '0'],
                ['Option 1', '1'],
                ['Option 2', '2']
            ],
            'default' => 0
        ]
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file_metadata', $tempColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('sys_file_metadata', 'my_field', '', 'after:description');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly ok. You should replace the array() with [].

And then replace:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('sys_file_metadata', 'my_field');
```

with:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('sys_file_metadata', 'my_field','', 'after:description');
```

Your custom field is then displayed after the description. Don't forget to add the field in the database as well.

Comment: I made your suggested changes, but the field is still missing. I am using TYPO3 10 if that makes a difference?

Comment: I just testet this in TYPO3 10.4.16. Works like a charme. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Oh I have realised it's putting it under the file info! What I am trying to do it get it under a media element. Like when you add it to a text/media element, or in the page properties as a relation. Can you advise?

Comment: For that you must customize an existing contentelement or create an own. Maybe this helps you by doing that: https://www.in2code.de/aktuelles/eigenes-content-element-in-typo3-bild-ueber-sys-file-reference-in-flexform/